# Dictionary Generator in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

This is my code which is supposed to generate a dictionary where the keys are numbers between 1 and 20 (both included) and the values are square of keys. The function should just print the values only.

```
d={}

d.update(dict(map(lambda i:({i:i**2}),[i for i in range(0,21)])))

print(d.values())
```

It gives me the following error:

```
 File "D:\python\py\new\dict_1_to_20_sqr.py", line 16, in <module>
    d.update(dict(map(lambda i:({i:i**2}),[i for i in range(0,21)])))

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Please point out my mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: ```{i: i**2 for i in range(0,21)}```, its that simple.

Comment: As @Sushanth points out, your method of creating a simple dictionary is overcomplicated. If you want to know why your method *failed*, take a look at the output of `list(map(lambda i:({i:i**2}),[i for i in range(0,21)]))`, and you'll see.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks, I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: thank you @Sushanth the answer was perfect.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list would probably fit this application better. Try this:

```
d = [ x**2 for x in range(21) ]
```

With this list, you could use `d[6]` to access the seventh item in the list, instead of having to use a dictionary. However, if you would still like to use a dictionary, you could do it in the following way:

```
d = { i: i**2 for i in range(21) }
```